# Set Nginx expires header for all js and css except some files

Tags: nginx

I use Nginx config to set js, css expires header

```
location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
  expires 30d;
}
```

How can I skip specific files (ex: abc.js, style.css) from being cached?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
    location ~* (file\.js|name\.css)$ {
        expires off;
    }
    expires 30d;
}
```

or

```
location ~* (file\.js|name\.css)$ {
    expires off;
}
location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
    expires 30d;
}
```

Comment: It should. Are you sure you are not testing with resources that already have 30 days associated? You can also place the specific location with the "expires off" above the other as shown in the edit.

Comment: Wouldn't the second `location` always be hit in your second example?

Comment: The first location block will take precedence.

Comment: Interesting, I didnt know that.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
  expires 30d;
}
location = /path/to/abc.js { expires off; }
location = /path/to/style.css { expires off; }
```

See the [location documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for a full explanation.